Outlook add-in generated from yeoman office add-in generator won't execute a function as intended
I'm trying to develop an Outlook add-in so I'm using the Yeoman generator for Office to generate a base template of an outlook add-in. I have sideloaded the add-in in Outlook.
Problem
This add-in simply implements a button labeled "Perform an action" which is expected to return a message in the Outlook interface that says "Performed an action", as specified in the following commands.js script that manages the button.
Office.onReady(() => {
});

function action(event) {
  const message = {
    type: Office.MailboxEnums.ItemNotificationMessageType.InformationalMessage,
    message: "Performed action.",
    icon: "Icon.80x80",
    persistent: true,
  };

  // Show a notification message.
  Office.context.mailbox.item.notificationMessages.replaceAsync("action", message);

  event.completed();
}

Office.actions.associate("action", action);

The issue is when I click the button, it doesn't seem to execute the function, or maybe it is trying to but the add-in is unreachable. Instead it's giving me a loading message "[add-in name] is working on your Perform an action request" which keeps going forever. See message
Steps to reproduce
There are no errors whatsoever in the http server logs that I'm running to serve the add-in's files. I'm not sure what I'm missing so I will go through the steps that I did to set up the environment and that you can reproduce.

Generate the project

yo office

When prompted I choose the following options
? Choose a project type: Office Add-in Task Pane project
? Choose a script type: JavaScript
? What do you want to name your add-in? panicbutton-test
? Which Office client application would you like to support? Outlook
? Which manifest type would you like to use? XML manifest


Install http-server

npm install --global http-server


Install and generate certs.

npm install --global office-addin-dev-certs

npx office-addin-dev-certs install


Copy certs to project directory
Run the server

http-server -S -C localhost.crt -K localhost.key --cors . -p 3000


Add the manifest.xml file to Outlook (Windows) and install the add-in.

Also I made sure the manifest.xml correctly points to the script's correct localhost URL.
Am I missing something to make this function as intended? Is it related to the JS script or the configuration of the project?
EDIT: Automatic sideloading (using npm start or npm run dev-server) has the same issue for me.

Are you testing this in Outlook Desktop or on the web? The desktop version has a bad debugging experience so it's tough to get right. Also, can I see the manifest?
